# WPF Ressource Dictionary match DataTemplate, Styles and Views for a Control depending of Type

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

I have problems with matching Ressource Dictionaries for a specific type in my project.

At start of my application my programm takes all .dll files in the folder and bind the .dlls to my project. After that I will search in all Assemblies for .xaml Files also the Ressource Dictionaries in my different dlls.

At the end I got a list with my Ressource Dictionaries.

Okay here is my problem now...How can I select the right dictionary for my type in the list View dynamicly. The second thing is how can I match the Dictionary Templates only to 1 control in my Window?

When the type of the items in my list view are changing check again for the right dictionary maybe i need another one

Here is an example of 1 dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PresentObjectDataTemplate">
<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <!-- My Style for my ListView Control-->
</Style>  
<!-- My Data Templates only for 1 Control-->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entity1}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding A1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding A2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Entity2}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding A1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding A2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My MainWindow has 3 Controls

1. A treeView to select my List
2. A listview to show the objects in the list
3. A contentcontrol to show the properties of a selected object

When I merge the dictionary to the window ressources my list view and my content control will use the datatemplates. But i want that the templates only used in the contentcontrol

Here a picture from my idea for better understanding
[myPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2EST.png)

Comment: Instead of window resources, you can load your styles into the `ContentControl`'s resources, so they will be applied only on `ContentControl`'s children.

Comment: how i can define it in the dictionary ?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't define "in the dictionary" to which scope it should apply.

Comment: Can u give me a sample? I want to bind the datatemplates from my dictionary to the content control in my main project